# Exposure in Poisson regression

Tags: regression, poisson-regression

Could somebody explain the concept of exposure in the context of Poisson regression and how it relates to the expected value of a Poisson distributed response?

Comment: The [motivating examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression#%22Exposure%22_and_offset) at the relevant Wikipedia page seems like a good place to start; e.g. consider the tree example where (impact of covariates being equal) different counts of trees would be expected if you looked at a large area or a small one. Could you identify where the examples and subsequent discussion are unclear or what you need beyond that?

Comment: Also see this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/difference-between-offset-and-exposure-in-poisson-regression

Comment: Another answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52846/7071).