# How do I describe this negative binomial regression with offsets in math and words?

Tags: r, regression, negative-binomial-distribution

I've been using a negative binomial model to compare the number of particles in the ocean of different sizes to their abundance.

My gam, in r code looks like this

```
gam(TotalParticles ~ log(lb), offset = log(binsize * vol), data = df, family = "nb")
```

I'm using gam, rather than glm, because the former can handle negative binomial regressions and poisson regressions with the same syntax and I was comparing the two at one point

Essentially I'm interested in the slope of the relationship between the log of size `lb` and the log of particle number `Total Paricles`.  The particle sizes have been binned by size, and so I normalize to the width of that bin. The particls are also collected in different volumes of water, so I also normalize to that volume `vol`.

I'm trying to express this in math and words in a corresponding manuscript. Right now, based on [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66791/where-does-the-offset-go-in-poisson-negative-binomial-regression), I'm writing the equation as:

$$ ln(\frac{E(Total\,Particles)}{Volume *Binsize}) = b_0 + b_1\,ln(Size) $$

My co-authors keep asking me what `E` means in this context. My understanding is that we are predicting an expected "negative binomial" distribution of total particle numbers from size.

So far I have written:

> The term on the left describes the expected volume and bin-size
> normalized count data, assuming a negative binomial distribution of
> residuals, with E referring to the conditional expectation of total particle numbers,
> assuming a negative binomial distribution.

I have two questions:

1. Does my equation actually correctly represent the linear model written in code? If not, is there a better way of writing it?
2. Is there a better way I can express in words what is going on on the left hand side of the equation?

Comment: [Related answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52364/7071) in the context of Poisson model, but that idea is identical.

Comment: Thanks. That gives me confidence that the equation that I am using is ok, unless of course NB are written differently than poisson models. That explanation also uses the E term, though I don't fully understand what that means, even from the provided post.

Comment: The expectations have the same form for NB and Poisson (though the parameters will of course be different). E stands for expected value here, which is a conditional mean. Technically you are modeling the mean of the number of particles given some covariates, not the number of particles itself.